# Cant drop Trigger because it "doesnt exist"

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following two Triggers

```
cascadeUserInsertionToRecommendations_tbl
```

and

```
afterinsertiontousers
```

Now below, just for completeness, is the result of "show triggers;"

```
+-------------------------------------------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Trigger                                   | Event  | Table     | Statement                                                                                                                                              | Timing | Created                | sql_mode                                            | Definer | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| cascadeUserInsertionToRecommendations_tbl | INSERT | users_tbl | INSERT INTO recommendations_tbl(recommendation_userid, recommendation_category, recommendation_manufacturer) VALUES(NEW.user_id, 'diverse', 'diverse') | AFTER  | 2019-09-02 12:32:46.19 | NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | @       | latin1               | latin1_swedish_ci    | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| afterinsertiontousers                     | INSERT | users_tbl | INSERT INTO recommendations_tbl(recommendation_userid, recommendation_category, recommendation_manufacturer) VALUES(NEW.user_id, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)     | AFTER  | 2019-09-02 15:48:39.52 | NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | @       | latin1               | latin1_swedish_ci    | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+-------------------------------------------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

Now the problem is that I just cant drop them :/
When I'm on foundationtests, the database where I created the triggers like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER afterinsertiontousers
    -> AFTER INSERT ON users_tbl
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> INSERT INTO recommendations_tbl(recommendation_userid, recommendation_category, recommendation_manufacturer) VALUES(NEW.user_id, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.016 sec)
```

this is what happens:

```
MariaDB [foundationtests]> DROP TRIGGER users_tbl.cascadeUserInsertionToRecommendations_tbl;
ERROR 1360 (HY000): Trigger does not exist
```

I already swapped to information_schema DB and deleted the above Trigger there. However, it still shows up here AND it still does its job, which it shouldnt...

I read about having to use "db5" on multiple other threads on SO, but I can't access this DB neither does it show up in my list of DBs when using "show databases";
So I'm somehow clueless on what I am missing Oo

Comment: Im on "foundationtests" and this is the DB where I ran the above Trigger Creation from. On which DB else should I execute the Drop Trigger?

Comment: Run `DROP TRIGGER cascadeUserInsertionToRecommendations_tbl`  ?  as `users_tbl` is the table not the database.. Also `DROP TRIGGER foundationtests.cascadeUserInsertionToRecommendations_tbl` should also work..